# Check if a container can be traversed backwards in C++

Tags: c++, templates, alias, type-traits

I'm writing a template which can take any container to store values into. I need to check if the container passed into the template wrapper can be traversed backwards (or, normatively speaking, meets the *ReversibleContainer* requirement). To provide a bit more context, here is a simple piece of code:

```
using container = ... // assume the container alias to represent the container
                      // passed in as a template parameter
...
using reverse_iterator = std::conditional_t<???, container::reverse_iterator, container::iterator>;
```

Is there any type trait for this or some other workaround? How can I implement this?

Comment: I don't think there's a built-in trait, but this looks like a straighforward `concept`-writing exercise, especially if you don't check the bidirectional-ness of the iterators, which isn't straighforward (unless you replace `LegacyBidirectionalIterator` with `std::bidirectional_iterator`, but then it's no longer strictly `ReversibleContainer`).

Comment: You might wanna to use `ranges::bidirectional_range<R>`.

Comment: What does "check" mean? You want the alias to be defined to `reverse_iterator`, if the container defines it, and `iterator` if not? Or if the container does not define `reverse_container` you want the code to be ill-formed? And what C++ standard are you using, there are different solutions for different C++ standards.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik I use C++20, but as there are different compilers used in our team, some features of the latest standard may not be affordable (we do not use concepts, for example)

Comment: one way to "check" is to simply do it and when the container does not support it it will fail to compile

Comment: I dont understand the `???` in your type trait. What do you want to do when the container has no `reverse_iterator` ? You want to reverse it anyhow? By using the forward iterator?

Comment: If the container is not bidirectional, then `reverse_iterator` is still defined as `container::iterator`, which makes no sense.

Comment: Ok, so C++17 or earlier. But what about a more precise explanation of what "check" means?

Comment: @SamVarshavchik Well, I guess I want to check if the `typename container::reverse_iterator` exists. I think this must be implemented using SFINAE, but not sure how

Comment: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/iterator_tags

Comment: @MarekR yes, iterator tags, so what?..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a fairly straightforward application of SFINAE, `has_reverse_iterator<T>` will evaluate to `true` if `T` defines a `reverse_iterator` member type.

```
#include <type_traits>
#include <vector>
#include <forward_list>

template<typename T, typename=void>
struct has_reverse_iterator : std::false_type {};

template<typename T>
struct has_reverse_iterator<T,
                typename std::void_t<typename T::reverse_iterator>>
    : std::true_type {};

template<typename T>
inline constexpr bool has_reverse_iterator_v=has_reverse_iterator<T>::value;

static_assert(has_reverse_iterator_v<std::vector<char>>);

static_assert(!has_reverse_iterator_v<std::forward_list<char>>);
```

Answer (score 1):

> A *ReversibleContainer* is a Container that has iterators that meet the requirements of either *LegacyBidirectionalIterator* or *LegacyRandomAccessIterator*.

You could therefore check if the container's iterator is a bidirectional iterator by using the [`std::bidirectional_iterator`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/bidirectional_iterator) `concept`:

```cpp
#include <iterator>
#include <ranges>

template <class C>
class Foo {
    static_assert(std::bidirectional_iterator<std::ranges::iterator_t<C>>);
};
```

```cpp
int main() {
    Foo<std::vector<int>> x;  // ok
    Foo<int[10]> y;           // ok
    // Foo<std::istream> z;   // error
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In C++20, we can use a [concept](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/requires) to define this requirement:

```
template<typename T>
concept has_reverse_iterator = requires
{
    typename T::reverse_iterator;
};
```

```
static_assert(has_reverse_iterator<std::vector<char>>);
static_assert(has_reverse_iterator<const std::vector<char>>);
static_assert(!has_reverse_iterator<std::forward_list<char>>);
static_assert(!has_reverse_iterator<const std::forward_list<char>>)
```

### [Live Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/YP7T5WjxW)